# Como prender um JMenuBar na parte de cima do JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Esqueci como fazer isso, me lembro que tenho que colocar um `BorderLayout(... NORTH);`. Como coloco um `JMenuBar` em um `JFrame`?

Comment: Douglas, removi um comentário seu da pergunta, e quero lhe deixar uma dica, não coloque esse tipo de coisa na pergunta, foque-se apenas na sua duvida, esse tipo de comentário é totalmente irrelevante para a dúvida e pode dar a entender que você não quer ter o minimo de esforço pra aprender, e sempre adicione um trecho relevante do que tentou fazer.  Da forma como estava, pode afastar boas respostas e até levar sua pergunta a fechamento, deixando você sem resposta.

Comment: A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não adiciona uma barra de menu como um componente qualquer, a forma de adicionar é:

```
seuJFrame.setJMenuBar(seuJMenuBar);
```

Caso queira mais detalhes, seguem alguns links da documentação explicando a respeito:

[How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

[How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)